# Getting problem in moving one file to different location

Tags: php

I am getting a problem in moving an image from a temporary folder to the current folder and my image is saved in the database but not going in the specified folder.

```
if(isset($_POST['Apply']))
{
  $leave = $_POST['documentstatus'];
  $documentstatus = "Pending";
  $filename=$_FILES["pfimg"]["name"];
  $tempname=$_FILES["pfimg"]["temp_name"];
  $folder=rand(222,333333).$filename;
  move_uploaded_file($tempname,"/student/".$folder);
  mysqli_query($db,"insert into documentdetails values(null,'$empid','$leave','$folder','$documentstatus')");
  echo "<script>window.location='documentupload.php';</script>";
}
```

Comment: What are directory permission for /student/ ? It should be writable.

Answer (score 2):

One issue was that you were referencing `temp_name` rather than `tmp_name` and also attempting to write a file to a location which did not necessarily exist.

The sql was vulnerable to sql injection - better to use a `prepared statement` with bound parameters - example given below.

```
if( isset( $_POST['Apply'], $_POST['documentstatus'], $_FILES['pfimg'] ) ){

    if( !function_exists( 'createdir' ) ){
        /*
            recursive build folder path and set
            permissions along the path.

            ex: createdir( '/folder/folder/folder', 0755 );
        */
        function createdir( $path=NULL, $perm=0644 ) {
            if( !file_exists( $path ) ) {
                createdir( dirname( $path ) );
                mkdir( $path, $perm, true );
                clearstatcache();
            }
        }
    }

    $leave = $_POST['documentstatus'];
    $documentstatus = "Pending";
    $filename=$_FILES["pfimg"]["name"];
    $tempname=$_FILES["pfimg"]["tmp_name"]; #   <---- tmp_name not temp_name

    $folder = rand( 222,333333 );
    $path = sprintf( '/student/%s', $folder );
    $target = sprintf( '%s/%s', $path, $filename );

    /* 
        as pointed out, create the folder structure 
        before attempting to write a file to it
    */
    createdir( $path );

    $status = move_uploaded_file( $tempname, $target );

    $sql='insert into `documentdetails` values (null,?,?,?,?)';
    $stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

    if( !$stmt )exit('Bad foo!');
    $stmt->bind_param('ssss',$empid,$leave,$target,$documentstatus);
    $result=$stmt->execute();
    /* better to do redirection in php but might cause `headers already sent errors` depending upon how this is called */
    header('Location: documentupload.php');
}
```

Comment: Warning: move_uploaded_file(): The second argument to copy() function cannot be a directory in C:\wamp\www\HRM\user\documentupload.php on line 68. i am getting  error on "$status = move_uploaded_file( $tempname, $target );"  line.

Answer (score 0):

You must create the direcory before using `move_uploaded_file()`

```
$folder= "/student/" . rand(222,333333) . "/";

if (!file_exists($folder)) {
  mkdir($folder);         
} 

$folder= $folder . $filename;
move_uploaded_file ($tempname, $folder);
```

Comment: Still, file is not moving to the specified folder

Comment: Do you get an empty `/student/rand` directory?

Comment: As @RamRaider pointed out you have a typo (temp instead of tmp). You should accept his answer for using prepared statements.